# Editing dependant picklists in a list view - is it possible?

Tags: list-view, dependent-picklist

I have 2 dependent pick lists on an object, which works correct.

Our users, use list views, to update their day to day records. The 2 specific dependent pick lists are visible on the list view, but they are not editable. (other fields are editable, we do not use record types)

My question: is it possible to edit dependent pick lists in a list view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline edit is not available for controlling or dependent picklists.

In this [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customviews_edit_inline_listview_lex_considerations.htm&type=5) you can find the list of fields and field types that aren’t inline editable:

- Built-in fields like Record ID or Created Date (never editable from the user interface)
- Compound fields including Name, address fields, and geolocation fields. To inline edit names, use the First Name and Last Name fields.
- **Controlling or dependent picklists**
- Custom date/time fields
- Encrypted text fields
- For orgs with person accounts enabled, if your list view is filtered by the Person Account record type, the Account Name field isn’t inline editable. If your list view is filtered by the Business Account record type, Account Name is inline editable. If your list view includes multiple record types, no fields are inline editable.
- Formula fields
- Standard fields of type date/time, auto number, rollup summary, record type, master-detail, long text area, rich text, checkbox, or hierarchy
- Fields that aren't on the page layout